# AlterDialog pops up twice - Android

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-alertdialog

I'm asking for permissions to enable GPS through the app. It works perfectly, however it just shows up twice.

Here's the code for the function:

```
public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_farm);

        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Not Enabled");

        alertDialog.setMessage("Do you wants to turn On GPS");


        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(KissanActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

This function is being called only once when I check for location permissions:

```
  public Location getLocation() {

    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        checkGPS = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        checkNetwork = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!checkGPS && !checkNetwork) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Service Provider Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showSettingsAlert();
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (checkNetwork) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Network", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                try {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        loc = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        Toast.makeText(this, "I've found your location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        textview.setText("Found Your Location");
                    }

                    if (loc != null) {
                        latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                        longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                        textview.setText("Got Your LatLong - "+latitude+" - "+longitude);
                        GetWeather gw;
                        gw = new GetWeather();
                        gw.execute();

                    }
                }
                catch(SecurityException e){

                }
            }
        }
        // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
        if (checkGPS) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"GPS",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (loc == null) {
                try {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        loc = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (loc != null) {
                            latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                            longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                            textview.setText("You Location Is \n");
                            textview.append("Latitude - "+latitude+" Longitude - "+longitude);

                            Toast.makeText(this, "Your Location Is "+latitude+" "+longitude , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (SecurityException e) {

                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return loc;
}
```

Comment: where are you calling `getLocation()`?

Comment: add the code of calling `getLocation()`

Comment: I'm calling getLocation() from onCreate - To check for the location when the activity starts and onResume to check if the user has enabled the location when the activity is resumed from settings.